# Discord.js: How to make bot log if someone was swearing?

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, discord.js, bots

I am node.js bot coder and curious how can I make my bot log in a specific channel if someone said bad word. My code is:

```
client.on('message', message => {
    if (message.author.bot) return;
    let rudeWords = ["censored", "censored", "censored", "censored", "censored", "censored", "censored", "censored", "censored", "censored", "censored", "censored", "censored", "censored", "censored", "censored", "censored", "censored", "censored", "censored", "censored", "censored", "censored"];
    if (rudeWords.some(word => message.toString().toLowerCase().includes(word))) {
        message.delete()
        message.reply('do not use that word here, thank you.').then(msg => 
        {msg.delete({ timeout: 3000 })
    })
}})
```

What should I add to this for bot to log if someone sweared? Help pls <3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can send messages to a specific channel either by `find` or `get` method. Find requires an arrow function, whereas get required the ID of the channel as a String.

**Eg**: **by get method:**

```
let logChannel = message.guild.channels.cache.get('the-channel-id');
logChannel.send("Someone sweared");
```

**by find method:**

```
let logChannel = message.guild.channels.cache.find(channel=>channel.name==='the-channel-name');
logChannel.send("Someone sweared");
```

Comment: thank you so much, can you additionally tell me, how can i replace 'some1 sweared' with '@user sweared'

Comment: No problem and i suppose, `msg.author` would give you the user, whos message had the swear word. So `msg.author.tag` or `msg.author.username` gives the tag and username respectively. Check more properties of the User in the [docs](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/User).

Answer (score 0):

[Array.Includes()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/includes)

```js
let rudeWords = ["censored", "censored", "censored"];
var message = "censored"
console.log(rudeWords.includes(message.toLowerCase()));
```

Comment: thank you but it isnt logging into the discord channel

Comment: it's just an example add your code to log